# How to decrease length numbers in python

Tags: python, numbers, int

I have to convert this value to `23.69` or `23.70` not like that talll number `23.69098712446352`

```
a=552.0
b=23.3
c=a/b
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.format` the output:

```
print("{:.2f}".format(c))
```

Or round:

```
round(c, 2)
```

Output:

```
In [9]: print(c)
23.6909871245

In [10]: print("{:.2f}".format(c))
23.69
In [11]: print(round(c, 2))
23.69
```

Answer (score 0):

Use round function -

```
c = round(a/b , 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:
    round(a.b, 2)

Or just for display use this:

```
>>> "%.2f" % 3.14159
'3.14'
>>> print("%.2f" % a)
```